# I'm trying to login with django. but always fail. why?

Tags: python, django

i'm doing my own project.
the project is signup, signin in django.
i make my own model. not django model.
i use AbstractBaseUser, and create my own model.
this model get name, id, companyname, companycode.
i succeed signup. get name, id, companyname, companycode. and save mysql.
but when i login with this information, always fail.
i think authentication function is error. but i don't know where is the error.
could you help me?

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password=None):

        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an name!'))

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company= company,
            companycode = companycode,
        )

        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company = company,
            companycode = companycode,
            password=password,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, verbose_name="이름")
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="아이디")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="회사")
    companycode = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="회사코드")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="생성날짜")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['userid', 'company', 'companycode']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All superusers are staff
        return self.is_superuser

    get_full_name.short_description = _('Full name')
```

backend.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from useraccount.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
class UseraccountBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
         username = kwargs['username']
         companycode = kwargs['companycode']

         try:
             useracc = User.objects.get(username=username, companycode=companycode)
             if check_password(companycode, kwargs['companycode']) is True:
                 return useracc.username
             '''
             if useracc.companycode.check_password(code) is True:
                 return useracc.username
                 '''
         except User.DoesNotExist:
             pass
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'useraccount/login.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name',None)
        code = request.POST.get('code',None)

        user = authenticate(username=name, companycode=code)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'useraccount/login_success.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'useraccount/login_fail.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'useraccount/signup.html')
@csrf_exempt
def signup_sign(request): #일반유저 회원가입
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['name']
        userid = request.POST['id']
        company = request.POST['company']
        code = request.POST['code']
        account = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company = company,
            companycode = code,
        )
        #login(request, account)
        account.save()
    return render(request, 'useraccount/success.html')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using the authenticate function make sure your user has is_active=True in the model

Comment: @Ayuka not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first problem is here:

```
companycode = kwargs['companycode']

[snip]

if check_password(companycode, kwargs['companycode']) is True:
```

`check_password()` takes two arguments -- a plaintext password and an encoded password.  You are passing the same value for both, so I would not expect that to return `True`.

(Bonus tip, you don't want to return `useracc.username`, which would be a string. You want to return `useracc` which should return a user object.)

Comment: Am i right? 1. change useracc.username -> useracc. 2. get user's password(encoded) and compare. example : username : aa , password : bb(encoded:adfdf1)-> encoded companycode , check_password(bb(adfdf1) , kwargs['companycode'])